# Retrieving HTTPBody from RestKit response

Tags: ios, restkit

I am using the postObject and putObject functions of restKit. I need to extract some info from the payload and put it in the header before sending it out.. any suggestions on how I can do that?

ex:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:object path:OBJECT parameters:nil success:success failure:failure];
```

I will probably have to do something like

```
// Create Payload for this request
// update header accordingly
// call postObject
```

I would like to avoid throwing away existing code..

Comment: You need to set headers specifically for each request made, or set global headers that apply to all of the requests you make (with the same object manager)?

Comment: Wain I am able to set the headers - thats not the issue here. The issue is that the header will be set based on the values of the payload. I need to create the JSON payload , calculate the header value, and then call putObject. My question is - since putObject is creating the request body for me so i am not creating it explicitly myself. Should I just create the payload as as additional step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by using all the params that I was passing before making the RK request.